# Google Maps V3 Marker not showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm writing the below script to add a marker on click, the map loads fine but when I click on it no marker is added and there are no errors in the console, anyone have any suggestions as to what might be going on?

```
function selectMapLocation()
{
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.7699298, -122.4469157)
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.LatLng, 
            map: map
        });
    });
}

function loadSelectMapLocation()
{
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=selectMapLocation';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote, it's a genuine question, there are no errors to show and the code runs with exception of the marker showing!?

Comment: read the documentation instead of using  a kind of "maybe it works"-code

Comment: @Dr.Molle, I did read the documentation, stackoverflow was a last resort, I've been trying to figure it out for the past 2 hours and for all intensive purposes the code did work as no errors or warnings where being displayed on screen or in the console. As you can see it was a minor typo on `LatLng` having to be `latLng` which is a very easy mistake to make and easy enough to over look. Thanks to the helpful user below I've been able to resolve it.

Comment: No, it wasn't only the `latLng`, where in the documentation did you read about the `setMap`-property(used in your code before the edit)?

Comment: @Dr.Molle, that was actually an older version of code I was using while trying to get it to work based off examples on the internet as I was running out of options, the code above is what I had prior to the suggested fix by the below user. As soon as it was pointed out I updated the code with the most recent code I'm using. Anyway its done, now, a helpful user has pointed out my error and I'm happy with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [google.maps.MarkerOptions object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) doesn't have a setMap property.

map | Map|StreetViewPanorama | Map on which to display Marker.

The [MouseClick event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent) doesn't have a LatLng property. It is latLng (javascript is case sensitive).

latLng | LatLng | The latitude/longitude that was below the cursor when the event occurred.

```js
function selectMapLocation()
{
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.7699298, -122.4469157)
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng, 
            map: map
        });
    });
}

function loadSelectMapLocation()
{
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=selectMapLocation';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
loadSelectMapLocation();
```

```html
<div id="map" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `map` property on object construction instead of `setMap`.

**EDIT**: also `LatLng` is `latLng`, as mentioned in another response.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng, 
    map: map
});
```

Comment: No difference, still no marker displaying and nothing in the browser console.